# How to select all tables from the database?

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access-2010

Good afternoon, whatever your timezone is ..
My question is,
 **Is there a way to select all tables? just like how we select all columns?**

Something like

```
 Dim cmdsql As String = "SELECT * FROM  *"
```

Situation:

I have 4 tables inside the database ("which I would not know the names if my client changes it") So I need a better way how to do those.

> I wanna `SELECT` all the columns, `FROM` all the tables store it in a dataset, so I can iterate
>   if it matches the search criteria.

**EDIT**: This is my search code by the way.

```
SearchDataset.Clear()
lstSearchResults.Items.Clear()
btnSearch.Enabled = False
Dim cmdsql As String = "SELECT * FROM *" '- This variable holds the SQL command.
            '-----------------------------------------
            ' Connect to the current connection string
            '----------------------------------------
            SYSTEM_MainClient.dbcon.Open()

            '-----------------------------------------
            ' Setup the Where Clause
            '----------------------------------------

            If cboSearchBy.Text = "StudentID" Then
                SearchAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(cmdsql + " WHERE " + cboSearchBy.Text + " = " + txtSearchbox.Text, SYSTEM_MainClient.dbcon)
            ElseIf cboSearchBy.Text = "Age" Then
                SearchAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(cmdsql + " WHERE " + cboSearchBy.Text + " = " + txtSearchbox.Text, SYSTEM_MainClient.dbcon)
            Else
                SearchAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(cmdsql + " WHERE " + cboSearchBy.Text + " like '" + txtSearchbox.Text + "'", SYSTEM_MainClient.dbcon)
            End If
            SearchAdapter.Fill(SearchDataset, "SearchResults")
            SYSTEM_MainClient.dbcon.Close()
            If SearchDataset.Tables("SearchResults").Rows.Count > 0 Then
                For i = 0 To SearchDataset.Tables("SearchResults").Rows.Count - 1
                    lstSearchResults.Items.Add(SearchDataset.Tables("SearchResults").Rows(i).Item("Last_Name").ToString + ", " + SearchDataset.Tables("SearchResults").Rows(i).Item("First_Name").ToString)
                Next
            Else
                SYSTEM_MainClient.ShowInformation("No records matched with the search '" + txtSearchbox.Text + "'.", "Database Search")
                txtSearchbox.Clear()
            End If
            btnSearch.Enabled = True
```

Basically what I want to happen, select all from all tables, and fill it in the dataset and iterate inside the dataset if there are matching result names based on the search criteria with my `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Here this Is the code to select all the tables from the ms access database

```
SELECT MSysObjects.Name AS table_name FROM MSysObjects
 WHERE (((Left([Name],1))<>"~") AND ((Left([Name],4))<>"MSys") AND ((MSysObjects.Type) In (1,4,6))) 
order by MSysObjects.Name
```

Making some alteration to this query will help to select columns of table

Comment: It gives me this exception

'Record(s) cannot be read; no read permission on 'MSysObjects'.' -